# Options for updating existing data in column while modifying the same column's data type

Tags: mysql

Is it possible in MySQL in a single statement to both modify the data type of a column and update the existing data in that column so it's compatible with the new data type? Or would I need to, for example, create a new column with the new data type, then use the original column's data to update the values of the new column, and then finally drop the original column?

I want to change an `int(11)` to a `time` column where the column's original `int(11)` data can range from `0` to `180` which represent 5 minute timeslots from 8am-11pm. So, for example, the original `int(11)` data of say `0` would need to get updated to the new `time` data of `08:00:00`, or `96` updated to `16:00:00`, etc..

Obviously if I try modifying the column's data type without any "intervention" on the existing data with the following:

`ALTER TABLE <table> MODIFY <column> time DEFAULT NULL`

...I'm guessing MySQL will simply not allow it to happen since my old data is likely not compatible with the new data type, and it will obviously also not know how to parse the data the way I want as described above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you'll have to do this in several steps as you describe.

Comment: Although it would require "2" steps, one to change the column and then another to change the data in them, you could always make a Stored Procedure that does the first step and then the second one and just CALL Stored_Procedure_Name()

Comment: Now if you must do stuff "by hand", use Microsoft Workbench to make the process more like tweaking an Excel file , so turn around time should be decent.

Comment: @easleyfixed not sure how I'd do this two steps as it seems like I'll need to create a new column first, update the data, then finally drop the original column. It's not a big deal though as I'll do the change in Java if that's what you mean by "by hand"

Comment: Ahh well in that case, if your environment allows installations, I would suggest you try out Workbench, you can drill into a table, create selects of that table of JUST the records you want to change, sort them like an Excel file .. heck .. export into actual Excel format if you want .. but a GUI way to do what you are doing.  And if you end up wanting to do a stored procedure to do it all in one set, it seems easier to build them in Workbench due to it giving real time visual validation of proper and improper statements.

Comment: Two things to keep in mind, ALWAYS CREATE TABLE (new table) SELECT * FROM (old table) so you have a backup to work with.  Granted it seems you probably know this, but with that done, you can play to your hearts content until you are happy, and if you fail, just create another copy and try again.  OH .. one more thing .. when you create the copy of the table .. it does NOT set the primary key .. you need to reset that .. but also something Workbench can assist.

Comment: For the record, I never use MySQL Workbench. I do agree with testing on a copy table, and write an SQL script to do the work. Once you have the script written correctly and tested, then it's easy to run it against your real table.

Comment: @easleyfixed and Bill thanks for the tips. Will definitely make sure all is working before updating production server and I guess I will just stick to creating new table like I normally would with new data type then copy/modify data over from old table. Thought there might be a shorter way to do it all in place but it's not that much more work  and maybe better practice to create a new table anyway.